# the navigation between modules of angular 2 takes between 20 to 40 seconds

Tags: html, angular, angular2-routing, angular-cli, angular-components

the navigation between modules of angular 2 takes between 20 to 40 seconds. because when I change the link in angle 2 to another component it takes a long time to load. this is what I am using.

my angular-cli.json

```
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
    "project": {
        "name": "md-pro-angular-cli"
    },
    "apps": [
        {
            "root": "src",
            "outDir": "dist",
            "assets": [
                "assets",
                "favicon.ico"
            ],
            "index": "index.html",
            "main": "main.ts",
            "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
            "test": "test.ts",
            "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "prefix": "app",
            "styles": [
                "../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css",
                "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
                "styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [                            
                "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
                "../src/assets/js/jquery-ui.min.js",
                "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
                "../src/assets/js/core/material.min.js",
                "../node_modules/arrive/src/arrive.js",
                "../node_modules/moment/moment.js",
                "../node_modules/chartist/dist/chartist.js",
                "../node_modules/twitter-bootstrap-wizard/jquery.bootstrap.wizard.js",
                "../node_modules/bootstrap-notify/bootstrap-notify.js",
                "../node_modules/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js",

                "../node_modules/nouislider/distribute/nouislider.min.js",
                "../node_modules/bootstrap-select/dist/js/bootstrap-select.js",
                "../node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js",
                "../node_modules/datatables.net-bs/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js",
                "../node_modules/datatables.net-responsive/js/dataTables.responsive.js",
                "../node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.js",
                "../node_modules/bootstrap-tagsinput/dist/bootstrap-tagsinput.js",
                "../node_modules/jasny-bootstrap/dist/js/jasny-bootstrap.min.js",
                "../src/assets/js/core/jquery.perfect-scrollbar.min.js",
                "../src/assets/js/plugins/jquery-jvectormap.js",
                "../src/assets/js/plugins/sweetalert2.min.js",
                "../src/assets/js/core/jquery.validate.min.js"

            ],
            "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
            "environments": {
                "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
                "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
        }
    ],
    "e2e": {
        "protractor": {
            "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
        }
    },
    "lint": [
        {
            "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json"
        },
        {
            "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
        },
        {
            "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
        }
    ],
    "test": {
        "karma": {
            "config": "./karma.conf.js"
        }
    },
    "defaults": {
        "styleExt": "css",
        "component": {}
    }
}
```

my package.json.

```
{
  "name": "md-angular-cli-pro",
  "version": "1.6.1",
  "license": "http://md-pro-angular.creative-tim.com/documentation/tutorial",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/creativetimofficial/material-dashboard-pro-angular.git"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "1.0.0-beta.0",
    "@angular/animations": "4.4.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
    "@angular/common": "4.4.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.4.4",
    "@angular/core": "4.4.4",
    "@angular/forms": "4.4.4",
    "@angular/http": "4.4.4",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.4.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.4.4",
    "@angular/platform-server": "4.4.4",
    "@angular/router": "4.4.4",
    "angular2-material-datepicker": "0.5.0",
    "animate.css": "3.5.2",
    "arrive": "2.3.1",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.5",
    "bootstrap-material-design": "0.5.10",
    "bootstrap-notify": "3.1.3",
    "bootstrap-select": "1.12.2",
    "bootstrap-tagsinput": "0.7.1",
    "chartist": "0.9.4",
    "chartist-plugin-zoom": "0.4.0",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "datatables": "1.10.12",
    "datatables.net-bs": "1.10.12",
    "datatables.net-responsive": "2.1.1",
    "eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "4.17.47",
    "fullcalendar": "3.4.0",
    "googleapis": "19.0.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jasny-bootstrap": "3.1.3",
    "jquery": "1.12.4",
    "jquery-validation": "1.17.0",
    "jvectormap": "2.0.4",
    "moment": "2.18.1",
    "moment-timezone": "0.4.0",
    "ng2-nouislider": "1.6.1",
    "ng2-select": "1.2.0",
    "ngx-chips": "1.4.6",
    "nouislider": "9.2.0",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "1.1.0",
    "primeng": "^4.2.4",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "sweetalert2": "6.10.1",
    "twitter-bootstrap-wizard": "1.2.0",
    "uglify-js": "1.3.5",
    "validate": "3.0.1",
    "web-animations-js": "2.2.2",
    "zone.js": "0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.4.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.4.4",
    "@types/bootstrap": "3.3.32",
    "@types/chartist": "0.9.34",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/jquery": "1.10.31",
    "@types/node": "6.0.73",
    "codelyzer": "2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "3.2.0",
    "karma": "1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "protractor": "5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "2.0.0",
    "tslint": "4.5.0",
    "typescript": "2.4.2"
  }
}
```

I have searched and applied several things, however nothing has worked for me

Comment: Right-Click Inspect, look in network tab for better exposure of what's going on.

Comment: Check With Your Routing you might be implementing something before routing b/w the links.

Comment: If he's been watching, only I do not find anything weird, does something sound in the angular version?